# Which type of female connector is this?

Tags: pcb, identification, connector, surface-mount, header

I am reverse engineering a smart LED bulb. I have almost got the all of the components, but one thing I couldn't get is the connector highlighted below.

The LED bulb has 2 PCBs: the vertical PCB has a right angle male header that mates with the horizontal PCB's female SMD connector, which is what I am looking for.

Does anyone know what this female connector is called?

As shown in this [LED bulb tear-down](https://www.ednasia.com/teardown-bluetooth-enhanced-led-bulb/).

[image]

Comment: Show us a side view and dimensions (external and socket center-to-center).

Comment: I couldn't add picture here. So you can follow this specific link https://www.ednasia.com/teardown-bluetooth-enhanced-led-bulb/ it can help you to visualize.

Comment: What error message do you get when trying to upload images?

Comment: I can't add an image in the comments.

Comment: It is much better to insert new information into the original question as comment threads can become lost or buried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Nedd for assisting me finding the specific connector. Due to his in-depth details for a connector. I have ultimately found one.

Basically this is a Chinese website that specifically categorize LED bulbs connector

You can view them here
https://www.jkuncn.com/products/led-series/led-bulb-connector

Answer (score 12):

These are generally known as board to board connectors, in this case more specifically as "Bottom Entry" board to board connectors. The picture below shows examples of both top entry and bottom entry types.

[image]

Picture from:
https://www.gradconn.com/News/Connectors-Demystified-Bottom-Entry-Board-to-Board-Connectors

As a minimum pass-through holes for the pins are needed in the PCB.
For a flush mount type (as in your example) a larger cut out is required.

The next picture is of open frame versions that better illustrate the concept.
[image]
Picture from:
https://www.icrex.co.jp/english/products/smt/socket.html

Some types allow both top and bottom entry and are often known as "Dual Entry" or simply "Top or Bottom Entry" connectors.

One more style that I've seen used on some low cost LED bulbs is a Poke-In type. These more or less create a locking fit onto the inserted wire or pin.

[image]

Picture from:
https://datasheets.kyocera-avx.com/PHMicroSingleVertical_70-9296.pdf

Comment: I got the point but can you share a part number for 4 pin surface mounted female bottom entry connector. I have searched a lot on Digi-key but couldn't find one.